# Can it possible injecting javascript to dom which is loaded after using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `div` with id `#id1` which contains links. Whenever I click on links, I make an AJAX call which also returns other links from server.

Now what I am doing is replacing the old links by new ones in `#id1` using JQuery `replaceWith()` method. By doing so, I maintain the `id` of `div` which is `#id1`.

What I am trying to achieve here is get another bunch of links from server by clicking in those newly occupied links on `div` with `#id1` and continuously so.

Is it possible to write a script like that?

```
<div id = "id1">
<ul>
<li><a href ="test/show/1">link1</a></li>
<li><a href ="test/show/2">link1</a>link2</li>
....
</ul>
</div>
 <script> 
  $('#id1 a').on(click, function(){
     $.ajax({
            url: '/test/test_now?page=' + page,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                   $('#id1').repalceWith(response.links);
            },
            error: function() {

                alert('An error occurred');
            }
        });</pre>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Without seeing any code and more specific information it's hard to say much else.

Comment: I thought I have explain my problem clear enough.

Comment: Its unclear what help you need.  @Pointy answered Yes to your question.  Can you add a small (as possible) code snippet to show what you have done, and specifically point out the area that you don't understand?

Comment: After replacing the existing links with links returned from ajax call the click event on link doesnt call ajax call this time  with same script. @Pointy

Answer (score 1):

As Pointy said, I think you need to be more specific, but I think is a job for templating, one of my favorites (for the small size) is [Template7](http://www.idangero.us/template7/#.Vo6PuBXhBhE).

You create a template in a script tag like this in the foot of your html:

```
<script id="template" type="text/template7">
  <ul>
    {{#each links}}
    <li>
      <a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

and then with jQuery or JS

```
var template = $('#template').html();

// compile it with Template7
var compiledTemplate = Template7.compile(template);

// Now we may render our compiled template by passing required context
var context = {
    links:[
        {text:'Text',url:'http://www.example.com'}
    ]
};

var html = compiledTemplate(context);
$('#id1').html( html );
```

You can include the context from wherever you want and each time you receive new links, just update the context and reuse the compiled template and replace the html again in your "#id1" div
Just don't forget to include the Template7's js script file in your html

Regards

Comment: I  dont want to only update the links, I want them working with same script as I mentioned above. Anw that is helpful.

Comment: The idea I have is that when you receive the answer from the ajax call , you can update the context (you can save it in an object outside the $.on), in this way you can store everything in the context instead of depending on the DOM elements, you can depend on this context